# What are the Session timeout timer resetting parameters in Java Web App?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, timer, session-timeout

I am using **Tomcat 7.0**, **Spring 4.0.2**, **Web Module 3.0** in eclipse for my web application. And I configured my session timeout in **app/web.xml** as well as **tomcat/conf/web.xml**.

```
<session-config><session-timeout>30</session-timeout></session-config>
```

I know that tomcat must reset timer for calculate this 30 min for invalidate session on some events. What are these parameters/events/action for resetting timer?

Comment: Basically, a request from the client to the server.

Comment: Hi, @LuiggiMendoza thanks for your reply. Can you help me to solve this, if possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649578/define-custom-events-actions-requests-for-resetting-timer-for-session-timeout-in