# How to restrict only one session at a time per user in Java Web App?

Tags: java, spring, session, authentication, restriction

I am using Tomcat 7.0, Spring 4.0.2, Web Module 3.0 in eclipse for my web application. There is one requirement in my application that **one user must not allow to login from two different clients**. Along with this I need to consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649578/define-custom-events-actions-requests-for-resetting-timer-for-session-timeout-in).

The solution I can think : 
--> Declaring one **static Set** at app level. 
--> Check before every check whether username contains in that **Set** or not, if contains then I will not allow to login. 
--> Add username in **Set** after every login in **Set**. 
--> Remove username after every logout from **Set**.

But I cannot think all scenarios when this solution will fail. I think when user will close browser directly, this will not work. Please help to find out all scenarios and also proper solution which will handle all scenarios. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is a client in your programm? a person or a user-name?

Comment: client=browser? and what do you want to achieve by that? o.O

Comment: Multiple browsers connecting can be controlled in a way by creating an entry into a database of current logged in users. The trick is to trap  the browser close to remove the entry. Other things to consider you may allow users to access the system however not access the same data from multiple pages. To get arround session sharing you can create a variable in `window.sessionStorage` this will give you a unique key you can access via javascript

Comment: I would recommend [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) which supports [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-concurrent-sessions) out-of-the-box. There is always the problem of the user closing the browser instead of logging off (I would guess that most users would close the browser instead of logging off).

Comment: will Spring Security handle closing browser directly?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security supports this out of the box. Can you migrate your authentication process to use Spring Security?

See section 2.3.3 Concurrent Session Management below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html

Comment: will Spring Security handle closing browser directly?