# Weird behaviour regarding Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference - System Properties

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, configuration, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7.0, Spring 4.0.2, Web Module 3.0 in eclipse for my web application.
And I configured my session timeout in app/web.xml as well as tomcat/conf/web.xml.

```
<session-config><session-timeout>10</session-timeout></session-config>
```

I am sending one request called **captureLastActiveTimeForCurrentFile** after every 5 mins.

I need to ignore one request (suppose, **captureLastActiveTimeForCurrentFile**) from updating **lastAccessedTime** of session.

According **http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Sessions** (**org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.ACCESS_SESSION**) default behavior of tomcat is : `every request that is associated with a session will cause the session's last accessed time to be updated if the request explicitly accesses the session.`

I am not accessing session explicitly from request (HttpServletRequest object) **captureLastActiveTimeForCurrentFile.** So According to my understanding tomcat should invalidate session after 10 min from any request done **which is accessing session explicitly**. But In my case tomcat never invalidate session because I am sending **captureLastActiveTimeForCurrentFile** after every 5 mins. But according to docs it should be. Can Anyone help me to understand what is happening here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I found some discussion regarding this topic [here](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Session-getLastAccessTime-ticking-td2192000.html). But still I am not getting actual problem.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is triggering a call to request.getSession()? An access valve maybe? Have you set STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE anywhere?

Comment: No I didn't set STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE anywhere because I want it's default behavior. But it's not happening :(