# Is it possible to disable jsessionid for particular request in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, lastaccesstime

Is there any way to keep one particular request out of session?
Ch.7.6 of the Servlet specification (both 2.5 and 3.0 versions) says: 
    `"The session is considered to be accessed when a request that is part of the session is first handled by the servlet container."`

I don't want that particular only one request (suppose `/captureLastFileActiveTime`) will be part of the session is first handled by the servlet container. All other requests should be part of the session is first handled by the servlet container. Is it possible?
I am using `apache-tomcat-7.0.35` as my web server.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That no session is allocated on the server when this URL is accessed?

Comment: I want to ignore my one url from lastAccessTime of session. refer my another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649578/define-custom-events-actions-requests-for-resetting-timer-for-session-timeout-in

Comment: see this as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903327/is-is-possible-to-ignore-particular-url-from-calculation-of-httpsession-getlasta

Comment: so you want to know whether it is possible to alter web container functionality by not using access to a certain `url` to count in the `getLastAccessedTime` calculation? - why?